# Taking middle X+3 and X-3 elements from array

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, slice

I am trying to find the middle element of a list and then take the next 3 items forwards and backwards and make a new list in python.

For example:

```
lst = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q]
x = my_func(lst)
print(x)
[f, g, h, i, j, k, l]
```

How would one accomplish this?

I know I can find the middle by doing this:
`middle_index = (len(lst) - 1)//2`
but I am a bit stuck on how to slice it afterwards.

Comment: what have you tried so far ? what's your efforts ?

Comment: I know i can find the middle index with `middle_index = (len(lst) - 1)/2` but I am kinda stuck there on how to slice it afterwards

Comment: [how to slice an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation) ? google search ?

Comment: [sliciing array in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation) i think you should go through this and it will help you

Comment: Thank you for the help saharara!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [list slices](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) and avoid `index out of range` errors like so:

```
def middle_slice(lst):
    middle = len(lst) // 2
    return lst[max(0, (middle - 3)) : min(len(lst), (middle + 4))]

for length in [9, 8, 2, 1, 0]:
    print(length, middle_slice(list(range(length))))
# 9 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
# 8 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
# 2 [0, 1]
# 1 [0]
# 0 []
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ?

```
def my_func(lst):
    middle = len(lst)//2
    nlst = lst[middle-3:middle]
    nlst += lst[middle:middle+3]
    return nlst

lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q']
x = my_func(lst)
print(x) #==> [f, g, h, i, j, k, l]
```